# Is there a way to alter a value in Request.Params["MyCustomKey"]

Tags: asp.net

I need to change a value in `Request.Params["MyCustomKey"]`

Is any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just don't need to alter Request.Params value. Why do you need that?

**Edit**:

I think the correct way to do this is pass `ID` separately of the `StringID`, so you will be able to get your 100 value from Request without parsing link button's text. Who forms `String ID 100` text?

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I use linkbutton and linkbutton's text passed as a Request.Params["StringID"] value which is i.e. "String ID 100", but, then, I need only "100" to use otherwise I would have to parse it in 6 places in the  client's code, so, therefore, I would like to alter it.

Comment: Also, it it's good practice to assign Request.Params["whatever"] to its own in-scope variable for consumption instead of using the Request object.  I'm sure your other code does not need to see the whole Request object.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your application architecture, but why not writing a static method for parsing or even a extension method? You shouldn't change the values in Request.Params